# what command print unicode escaped in python

Tags: python, utf-8

How to print strings escaped?

Example:

```
text_str = "żółć"
text_unicode = u"żółć"

print function(text_str)
'\xc5\xbc\xc3\xb3\xc5\x82\xc4\x87'
print function(text_unicode)
u'\u017c\xf3\u0142\u0107'
```

so, what function should I use?

**updated**
I need more than escape, because I need this in log, and throwing escaped sometimes leads me to unescaped results

Answer (score 2):

You want the `repr` output:

```
In [1]: text_str = "żółć"

In [2]: text_unicode = u"żółć"

In [3]: print repr(text_str)
'\xc5\xbc\xc3\xb3\xc5\x82\xc4\x87'

In [4]: print repr(text_unicode)
u'\u017c\xf3\u0142\u0107'
```

There are also `'string_escape'` and `'unicode_escape'`:

```
text_str = "żółć"
text_unicode = u"żółć"

print text_str.encode('string_escape')

print text_unicode.encode('unicode_escape')
```

But encoding `'unicode_escape'` will  give you a str not unicode

Comment: note this does not work in python 3.x, where repr("żółć") is żółć", however `text_str.encode('unicode_escape')` still works, although it returns a byte object

Comment: string_escape/unicode_escape are different functions - i need ONE function for both variants.

Comment: I'm checking if repr is ok, but for now i wonder how to escape the escaped ;) because print is ok, but debug - shows unescaped....